# Dropping samples with tagged streams

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to accomplish the following behavior:

I have a continuous stream of symbols, part of which is pilot and part is data, periodically. I have the Correlation Estimator block that tags the locations of the pilots in the stream. Now, I would like to filter out the pilots such that following blocks will receive data only, and the pilots will be discarded by the tag received from the Correlation Estimator block.

Are there any existing blocks that allow me to achieve this? I've tried to search but am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, *technically*, the packet-header Demux could do that, but it's a complex beast and the things you need to do to satisfy its input requirements might be a bit complicated.

So, instead, simply write your own (general) block! That's pretty easy: just save your current state (PASSING or DROPPING) in a member of the block class, and change it based on the tags you see (when in PASSING mode, you look for the correlator tag), or whether you've dropped enough symbols (in DROPPING mode). A classical finite state machine!